# Pandas overwrite column names by position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading in a csv, and I'd like to overwrite the first two column names.

- I can't use `df.rename(columns={0:'name 1', 1:'name 2'})` because the columns aren't called 0 and 1. They have names, I just want to throw them out.
- It seems like

  ```
  df.columns.values[0] = 'name 1'
  df.columns.values[1] = 'name 2'
  ```

  has serious issues because afterwards, `df['name 1']` gives me a KeyError.
- What would be ideal would be `pd.read_csv(file, names=['name 1', 'name 2', ...]`. Curiously, this renames col 3 "Ellipsis" and doesn't have the desired effect.

Any ideas for how to do this sensibly in pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.columns = ['name 1', 'name 2'] + df.columns[2:].tolist()
```